# How to use built-in SVG as Background Image?

Tags: html, css, svg, background-image

```html
<div class="svg-background"></div>

<svg id="svg-source" viewBox="0 0 24 16" fill="none">
     <path d="M23.8475 7.18155C23.6331 6.88825 18.5245 0 11.9999 0C5.4753 0 0.36647 6.88826 0.152297 7.18127C-0.0507658 7.45952 -0.0507658 7.83691 0.152297 8.11517C0.36647 8.40846 5.4753 15.2967 11.9999 15.2967C18.5245 15.2967 23.6331 8.40842 23.8475 8.1154C24.0508 7.8372 24.0508 7.45952 23.8475 7.18155ZM11.9999 13.7143C7.19383 13.7143 3.03127 9.14243 1.79907 7.64782C3.02968 6.15189 7.18352 1.58241 11.9999 1.58241C16.8057 1.58241 20.968 6.15349 22.2007 7.6489C20.9701 9.14478 16.8163 13.7143 11.9999 13.7143Z" fill="#073255"/>
    </svg>

<style>
  .svg-background {
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    background-image: url(#svg-source);
  }
</style>
```

I've tried with `#` sign - but no result.
I want to use built-in SVG file as background pattern.

I need to achieve 2 purposes

1. Avoid duplication SVG element on the page
2. Avoid having external SVG image.

Any ideas?

Comment: is this good for you; https://jsfiddle.net/82qc7nt9/ ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, good enough, I'll use your solution, if I don't find better one.
I've researched this could be achieved with clip-path property similiar way as I tried.

Comment: so you are ok for a CSS solution to create the shape?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, The task could be achieved by your way and with clip-path way.
I thing these 2 ways are good enouph for the problem.